# Grouping and sum up all values per day, month and year in SQL

Tags: mysql, group

I have a table like this:

```
"time","value"
"2023-01-28 01:00:03.520","741"
"2023-01-28 14:14:30.520","509"
"2023-01-28 14:16:07.238","584"
"2023-01-28 14:17:49.630","562"
"2023-01-28 14:19:28.024","572"
"2023-01-28 14:21:10.336","569"
"2023-01-28 14:22:52.757","577"
"2023-01-28 14:24:29.733","583"
"2023-01-28 14:26:12.163","581"
"2023-01-28 14:27:50.475","576"
"2023-01-28 14:29:32.869","578"
"2023-01-28 14:31:15.612","580"
"2023-01-28 14:34:35.110","588"
"2023-01-28 14:36:16.407","598"
"2023-01-28 14:37:58.818","613"
"2023-01-28 14:39:35.873","642"
"2023-01-28 14:43:01.070","653"
"2023-01-28 14:46:21.825","662"
"2023-01-28 14:47:58.777","663"
"2023-01-28 14:49:41.514","664"
"2023-01-28 14:51:23.907","666"
"2023-01-28 14:53:00.869","667"
"2023-01-28 14:54:46.089","663"
```

Now I want to sum up all values which are saved ion one day and display them in a group in SQL.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(time), SUM(VALUE) 
FROM 
    item0364 
GROUP BY
    MONTH(time)
```

but it doesn't do as expected.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Which dbms is this ?

Comment: Then group by day month year

Comment: group by day and month and year and i am using mysql

Comment: Why would you be expecting a group by *month* to aggregate by *day*? What use is your sample data for aggregating by day when every row is the same day?? You don't show your *expected* result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`group by ... with rollup`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to get all results with one query:

```sql
Select YEAR(time), MONTH(time),  DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d'), SUM(VALUE) 
FROM item0364 
group by YEAR(time),MONTH(time), DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') WITH ROLLUP
```

Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MG-8DA7C).

Answer (score 0):

To group by YEAR use `YEAR()` function or `DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y')`  :

```
Select YEAR(time), SUM(VALUE) 
FROM item0364 
group by YEAR(time)
```

To group by MONTH use `MONTH()` function or `DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m')`  :

```
Select MONTH(time), SUM(VALUE) 
FROM item0364 
group by MONTH(time)
```

To group by day then use `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d'), SUM(VALUE) 
FROM item0364 
group by DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/oBcbo4zS)

Comment: Rather than date_format, to group by day just use date(time)